# What kind of pipe adapter for irrigation system in garden bed?

Tags: vegetables, irrigation

I have planted a garden and have a pop up from my irrigation system that is capped. If I loosen the cap too much water comes out flooding the plants nearest to the pipe.

I am wondering if there is something I can attach to this to slowly water the plants throughout the bed.

[image: garden and irrigation pipe]
[image: irrigation pipe closeup]

Comment: What are you mulching the garden with?

Comment: @Jurp hadn’t decided yet. If there’s something that will work better with a specific irrigation system I am open to recommendations on both.

Comment: There are many different sprinkler heads available , you should be able to find one that will do what you want.

Comment: @blacksmith37 so just a basic sprinkler head will screw onto this?

Comment: You may need a male/female fitting but there are both male and female thredad heads.

Answer (score 1):

There are commonly available adapters to convert from a pop-up to driplines. Some even include a pressure regulator for the dripline, or valves per dripline.

Complexity and price vary, mostly in tandem.